# Inquirer Not Installing In Nodejs

Tags: node.js, json, typescript, npm, yarnpkg

```
                   :***Hey Bro I Am making A Calculator With Typescript/JavaScript ***:
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
                               :***immediately This Error Come***:
                               :***Any One Can Solve This Error???***:
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

PS C:\Users\RanaG\Desktop\TS Projects\project00_calculator\tsconfig.json-master\tsconfig.json-master\src> npm start
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

> tsconfig.json@1.0.7 start
> node src/index.js

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module './internal/Observable'
Require stack:

- C:\Users\RanaG\Desktop\TS Projects\project00_calculator\tsconfig.json-master\tsconfig.json-master\node_modules\rxjs\index.js
- C:\Users\RanaG\Desktop\TS Projects\project00_calculator\tsconfig.json-master\tsconfig.json-master\node_modules\inquirer\lib\ui\prompt.js
- C:\Users\RanaG\Desktop\TS Projects\project00_calculator\tsconfig.json-master\tsconfig.json-master\node_modules\inquirer\lib\inquirer.js
- C:\Users\RanaG\Desktop\TS Projects\project00_calculator\tsconfig.json-master\tsconfig.json-master\src\index.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
  at Object. (C:\Users\RanaG\Desktop\TS Projects\project00_calculator\tsconfig.json-master\tsconfig.json-master\node_modules\rxjs\index.js:3:20)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
  'C:\Users\RanaG\Desktop\TS Projects\project00_calculator\tsconfig.json-master\tsconfig.json-master\node_modules\rxjs\index.js',
  'C:\Users\RanaG\Desktop\TS Projects\project00_calculator\tsconfig.json-master\tsconfig.json-master\node_modules\inquirer\lib\ui\prompt.js',
  'C:\Users\RanaG\Desktop\TS Projects\project00_calculator\tsconfig.json-master\tsconfig.json-master\node_modules\inquirer\lib\inquirer.js',
  'C:\Users\RanaG\Desktop\TS Projects\project00_calculator\tsconfig.json-master\tsconfig.json-master\src\index.js'
  ]
  }
  PS C:\Users\RanaG\Desktop\TS Projects\project00_calculator\tsconfig.json-master\tsconfig.json-master\src>

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
                                        :***For This I do ***:
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

PS C:\Users\RanaG\Desktop\TS Projects\project00_calculator\tsconfig.json-master\tsconfig.json-master\src> npm install inquirer
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

changed 40 packages, and audited 599 packages in 1m

40 packages are looking for funding

40 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

13 vulnerabilities (1 moderate, 9 high, 3 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
           [enter link description here][1]:***But This Cannot Perfect Any One Help Me ***:
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try running `npm install rxjs` first which is a dependency for observable. Also, would highly suggest you reformat the question because I got dizzy trying to go through with all the decorations.

Comment: Edtimer!                        
    Oh! Thank You Bro:                                            My Inquirer  is not working on this time Oh God But only I run a single command that is: 
                             npm install rxjs                    
 So my Inquirer is still working now I am Very 
                           Thanks of Edtimer! –